# Does the order of columns in the table matter?

Tags: sql-server

We have a number of projects big and small - most (if not all) of them use at least one SQL Server DB. All of them have different environments set up. Typically: dev (1+), QA, UAT, Live.
It is also common for us to release various code updates to different environments independently of each other. Naturally some of those updates come with schema update scripts such as

```
alter table foo add column bar
go
update foo set bar=... where ...
```

Sometimes made by hand, other times using Red Gate SQL/Data Compare.

Anyway where I'm going with this is that often different environments for the same project end up with different order of columns. Is this a problem? I don't really know... 
Does column order have any performance implications? Anything I could be missing?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, column order is not significant.  In actuality, the order that column data is stored on disk may itself be different than the order you see in client tools, as the engine reorders the data to optimize storage space and read/write performance (putting multiple bit fields into a single memory location, aligning columns on memory boundaries, etc..  )

Comment: @marc_s: of course there are references... http://www.sqlskills.com/BLOGS/PAUL/post/Inside-the-Storage-Engine-Anatomy-of-a-record.aspx or MSDN/BOL too

Answer (score 3):

Not really - in 95% of your cases, there's no difference in the column ordering. And from a relational theoretical point of view, column order in a table is irrelevant anyway.

There are a few edge cases where column order might have a slight impact on your table, most often when you have a large number of variable size fields (like VARCHAR). But that number needs to be really large, and your fields (their size) needs to be really massive - in such a case, it can be beneficial to put those variable size fields at the end of the table in terms of ordering the columns.

But again: that's really more of a rare edge case, rather than the norm.

Also, mind you: SQL Server has no means of reordering columns, really. You can do that in the visual table designer - but what SQL Server does under the covers is create a new table with the desired column ordering, and then all the data from the old table is copied over. That's the reason this is a very tedious and time consuming operation for large tables.

Comment: Yes, know about need to recreate table to reorder columns, however Charles Bretana seem to be saying that order of columns in SQL Studio is not the same as it actually stored in the DB, which kinda contradicts that?

Comment: @liho1eye: yes, I was surprised to read that, too - not sure if that's true and can't find any reference to that fact, either.

Comment: @liho1eye, @marc_s: if you look at on-disk storage, fixed length columns come first then variable length. The old adage about "strings last" is rubbish IMHO. http://www.sqlskills.com/BLOGS/PAUL/post/Inside-the-Storage-Engine-Anatomy-of-a-record.aspx or MSDN/BOL too

Comment: This is totally wrong. Order of columns can impact the size of the table and the size of the database, as well as raise errors which we might get when we use one order over the other! The issues starts when we change the table structure (add/remove columns for example). To fully understand the topic you need some knowledge of SQL Server internals and to use few undocumented elements in order to examine the physical structure of the table, but a simple demo without full explanation which any newbie can execute [you can see here](http://ariely.info/Blog/tabid/83/EntryId/243/).

Comment: @RonenAriely; I don't see how you can tell, in advance, what columns you are likely to remove. Tools like Entity Framework employs a temp table when modifying the table structure, which might be a good solution for those of us with smaller databases.

Comment: Good day @9Rune5, I did not discuss in this thread, how we can know the future or read minds but only about the facts. Moreover, if you will/did watch my lecture about the topic then you know what you should do and not only what is the issue. I presented it a few times in English and once in Hebrew during different events/conferences. There is a recording of my lecture in the DATA PLATFORM SUMMIT 2020 as well. I recommend to watch one of the recordings for more information. By the way, In general I usually recommend not to use ORM when you are looking for performance :-)